# How to redirect using getStaticProps?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I have a nextjs application with simple user authentication. That means there are some protected routes that I don't want logged out user to get access to. The app compiles successfully in development build and works as expected. But when I use `next build`, I get an error saying -

`Error occurred prerendering page "/createNewAdditionalInfo". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error`

`Error: 'redirect' can not be returned from getStaticProps during prerendering (/createNewAdditionalInfo)`.

Here's the code -

```
export async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
    let userObject;
    let id;
    const cookie = parseCookies(ctx);
    if (cookie.auth) {
        userObject = JSON.parse(cookie.auth);
        id = userObject.id;
    }
    if (!id) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                permanent: false,
                destination: '/',
            },
        };
    }

    return {
        props: {},
    };
}
```

Comment: `Error: 'redirect' can not be returned from getStaticProps during prerendering ` what is not understand here?

ps. You are in React, you can use `useEffect` hook for check redirect or not? :)

A better answer is here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14890

Comment: User can access the page for some seconds before getting redirected. As useEffect runs after initial render, not before. I need some way to redirect page from server side.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I was trying to run `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` on firebase hosting. Firebase hosting only supports static site hosting. For anything backend related you have to use firebase functions.

I switched my hosting provider from firebase to vercel and everything works as it should be.

Answer (score 13):

redirect from getStaticProps in nextJS

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const db = await getDB()

  //get id from url
  const id = params.postId

  //find post in db
  const post = await db().collection("posts").findOne({ _id: id })
  

  // The Redirect Happens HERE
  //if no post was found - go to Home page
  if (!post) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      post: JSON.stringify(post),
    },
  }
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any documentation about `redirect` inside of `getStaticProps` ? Can you add a link ? I can't find any information about redirect in getStaticProps, e.g. on [nextjs.org / data-fetching / get-static-props](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props). It seems to work though.

Comment: Links can break, but maybe it's worth adding it to the answer: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#redirect

Answer (score -2):

From the asker's comments:

> I need some way to redirect page from server side.

Next.js provides this, see the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#redirect).

You can achieve this by just switching the function `getStaticProps` to `getServerSideProps`. The entire function will execute on the server and your redirection will happen.

e.g.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return {
    redirect: {
      permanent: true,
      destination: 'https://giraffesyo.io',
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: The `getServerSideProps` function does NOT accept a `redirect` props as return value. Check the `GetServerSidePropsResult` type definition. If you try anyway, you'll get following error : 

> Error: Additional keys were returned from `getServerSideProps`. Properties intended for your component must be nested under the `props` key, e.g.:

Comment: @pyrou I've updated my answer with a link the the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#redirect)